# Package com.facebook.react.defaults does not exist in react native 0.64.2

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-studio, facebook

I need to downgrade the react native version 0.72.1 to 0.64.2 in a project.
Everything seems correct, I can build and run the project, but when I try to import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint I get the error that the package does not exist.

[image]

I'm trying to import this package because it exists in the project in version 0.72.1 but I don't know if it exists in react native version 0.64.2

Is there any way to import this package in version 0.64.2 or do what I'm trying to do in MainActivity.java in another way?

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.neaglebank;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "SampleReactNative";
  }
  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
            this,
            getMainComponentName(),
            // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
            DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
  }
}
```